# Different colors in UMAP

Tags: scrnaseq, seurat, 10x-genomics, umap

I have integrated top ten TCR clones into Seurat object something like below

[image]

You are seeing some clones are expressed in more than one cells

So in Seurat I have something like

```
> head(pbmc@meta.data$highlight)
[1] NA                              "CAGVDSNYQLIW_CASSPVAGGSYNEQFF" NA                             
[4] NA                              NA                              NA
```

Based on the number of cells in which each clone is expressed, I want to rank clones and says how percentage of cells expressed each clone these figures below

[image]
Can you help me with this please?